# how to check the month on datepicker angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker, angular8

I have a small seat booking app. When a reservation is made, a colored dot will appear on the reserved date in the angular material calendar (datepicker). The problem is that the booking dot is shown on all the months and not on the booked month, that is, if I book on September 5th, the dot is seen both in October and in November and in December and so on for all months of the year . I have developed this code to add the dots in the calendar, could you give me a clue / help on how to put the dot only in the month in which I booked?
Thank you very much and sorry for my ignorance but I am really new in this field

```
dateClass() {
  return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
    const arrDay = this.unavailableDates;
    const arrDisp = this.reservDate;
    let resp = 'tutte';

      for (const il of arrDisp) {
      if (date.getDate() === il.getDate()) {
        resp =  'disponibiles';
        return resp;
      }
}
    for (const el of arrDay) {
      if (date.getDate() === el.getDate()) {
        resp =  'non-disponibile';
        return resp;
      }
    }
    return resp;
  };

}}
```

Comment: getDate() of a Date object return the "day of the month", do you want to say getTime()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I think you want to compare the month and the year, rather the date.

dateClass() {
  return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
  let resp = 'tutte';
    const unavailableDate = arrDay.some(d => d.getMonth() === date.getMonth() && d.getFullYear() === date.getFullYear());

     const reserveDate = arrDisp.some(d => d.getMonth() === date.getMonth() && d.getFullYear() === date.getFullYear());

    return unavailableDate ? 'disponibiles' : reserveDate ? : 'non-disponibile' : resp ;
  };
}
```